# Is an Hamiltonian like this non-degenerate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, matrix-elements

If I have a system of only two energy levels $E_0$ and $E_1$ and an Hamiltonian

$$H=\begin{pmatrix}
E_0 & 0 \\
0 & E_1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

can the Hamiltonian be both degenerate and non-degenerate? Or does it have to be non-degenerate?

Comment: It would appear obvious to me that it's degenerate if $E_0 = E_1$ and non-degenerate otherwise just from the definition of what (non-)degenerate means. Is there a trick to this question you're not telling us?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I do not understand. If $E_0<E_1$ why the Hamiltonian would be non-degenerate? You can't have two different eigenvalues both degenerate?

Comment: What do you think "degenerate" means?

Comment: In this context, a Hamiltonian is non-degenerate if all of its eigenvalues are distinct (more technically, each eigenspace is 1-dimensional). In this case, your Hamiltonian is non-degenerate if the two eigenvalues are different and degenerate if they’re the same. It sounds like you have some other definition of degeneracy in mind?

Comment: @J.Murray An eigenvalue $\lambda$ associated with two or more different and linearly independent eigenvectors is said degenerate. If the two levels are different, couldn't they still have degenerate eigenspaces? I think I misspelled the question, by $E_0$ and $E_1$ I mean the two eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian, couldn't there be two linearly independent eigenstates corresponding to the same eigenvalue in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Hamiltonian is $H=\pmatrix{E_0 & 0 \\ 0 & E_1}$ with $E_1\neq E_0$, then its eigenvalues are $E_0$ and $E_1$ and correspond to the eigenspaces $\mathrm{span}\left\{\pmatrix{1\\0}\right\}$ and $\mathrm{span}\left\{\pmatrix{0\\1}\right\}$, respectively.  These eigenspaces are clearly 1D, and so the Hamiltonian is non-degenerate.

---

If the Hamiltonian is $H=\pmatrix{E &0\\0&E} = E \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$, then its only eigenvalue is $E$ and the corresponding eigenspace is all of $\mathbb C^2$ which is 2D, and so the Hamiltonian is degenerate.